# columns names are not matching with row values as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,  2 , 3],

                   'question': ['first country visited?', 'first city visited?' , 'two cities we love?'],
                   'answer1': ['UK', 'Paris', 'CA'],
                   'answer2': ['US', 0.4, 'Paris'],
                   'answer3': ['CA', 'London', 'London'],
                   'correct': [['UK'], [0.4], ['London, Paris, 0.4']]
                   })
```

data:

```
    id  question                 answer1    answer2   answer3   correct
0   1   first country visited?      UK       US        CA       [UK]
1   2   first city visited?         Paris   0.4       London    [0.4]
2   3   two cities we love?         CA     Paris      London    [London, Paris, 0.4]
```

I am creating a new column to check if values in correct column are found in answer1 or answer2 or answer3 columns.

```
cols = data.filter(like='answer').columns
data['correct_column'] = data[cols].apply(lambda s: ','.join((m:=s.isin(data.loc[s.name, 'correct']))[m].index), axis=1)
```

output:

```
id  question                   answer1    answer2   answer3       correct                  correct_column
0   1   first country visited?        UK        US        CA        [UK]                     answer1
1   2   first city visited?           Paris     0.4       London    [0.4                     answer2
2   3   two cities we love?           CA        Paris     London    [London, Paris, 0.4]
```

I get an empty value in the third row. I have been trying for hours without success on my original data! Is there any better approach to achieve this? considering different data types in my original df like floats, int & Str ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get columns names as values if a condition is met in rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548598/get-columns-names-as-values-if-a-condition-is-met-in-rows)

Comment: Yes it worked for my example but I experienced more issues with data types and mask logic so I am looking for a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a longer version:

```
cols = data.filter(like='answer').columns

def app(s):
    (m:=[s[col] in (data.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])
    return ', '.join(cols[m])

data['correct_column'] = data[cols].apply(app, axis=1)
data['correct_column']
```

and shorter version that will accomplish the same thing:

```
data['correct_column'] = data[cols].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[(m:=[s[col] in (data.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])]) , axis=1)
data['correct_column']
```

which will produce:

```
0             answer1
1             answer2
2    answer2, answer3
Name: correct_column, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you Yusuf, again the code works perfectly on the example but I got an error in my original data (huge df) `TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.float64' is not iterable` is there a way I can handle the data types of all the df so the code works on it?

Comment: Sure. Can you post the line where the error occurs?

Comment: `----> 4     (m:=[s[col] in (df.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])`

Comment: I see. I think the problem might be that some of the values in the `correct` column may not be actually lists but floats which is causing the issue. Try to do a type check on that column as follows. If the value is not a list and just wrap the value in `list()`.

Comment: `df.correct.apply(type).value_counts()` shows `<class 'list'>    3034` all in list type but I am not sure if the issue could be because some lists in this column are with one value ex: `[3]` / `[0.3%]`/  `[11.2]` some data with special char `[Paris + London]` 
I tried to wrap the values inside the lists in string format but the `isin` function will throw an error too :(

Comment: A single value within a list should still work fine as the example above with 0.4 indicates. You should not use list() on the values that are already lists. Have you tried a debugger to see what row in the dataframe it throws an error to be precise?

Comment: Finally, I unified the data type wrapped `str` between columns that I compare using the short code you. provided:
`data['correct_column'] = data[cols].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[(m:=[str(s[col]) in str(data.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])]) , axis=1)`

Now everything is working after hours of searching .. Thanks Yusuf